# resize2fs LVM root on CentOS 6.6 64-bit guest on XenServer 6.2

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, xen, ext4, lvm

All the preparations to grow the ext4 root LVM partition on CentOS 6.6 64-bit running on XenServer 6.2 have been completed.

- Grow the `xvda` virtual disk on XenServer - check.
- Create `xvdaN` as LVM on CentOS guest using fdisk - check.
- `pvcreate /dev/xvdaN` on CentOS guest - check.
- `vgextend VolGroup /dev/xvdaN` on CentOS guest - check.
- `lvresize --extents /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` on CentOS guest - check.

Now I need to `resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`.  Here's the problem.

It's the root volume.  My understanding is that it cannot be resized while the VM is running - lest we corrupt the volume.  However, the volume is not recognized when I boot from the CentOS 6.5 LiveCD iso (there is no 6.6 LiveCD.)

So, how do I resize2fs a logical volume that cannot be touched with the VM running, and isn't recognized when the VM is not running?

Comment: I believe you can extend a live partition safely.

Comment: Thanks, Etan.  I was considering taking a snapshot of the VM and then attempting to resize online.
However, I've just run across the command "vgchange -aay" which should activate the volume group when booting from the LiveCD.  So, that will be my first attempt.  Failing that, I will attempt to resize online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the answer online...

1. Boot from LiveCD
2. Open a terminal
3. `sudo su -l`  Switch user to root
4. `vgchange -aay`  This is the magic.  It will automatically find and activate existing volume groups.
5. `e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`  Force check the volume for errors
6. `resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`  Add available space to volume
7. `e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`  Force check the volume for errors
8. `reboot`

...and viola, the root volume is now using the additional available space.